# How to parse result of Location.distanceBetween method?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using this to acquire distance between current location and the marker the user choose:

```
float[] distance = new float[1];
    Location currentLocation = PECApplication.getInstance().getLocationClient().getLastLocation();
    Location.distanceBetween(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude, distance);
```

but I just can't parse it into a rational number, like '30345' meters for example, it keep returning stuff like 'F@403202. So I want to know how I can convert this kind of denotation to a decimal..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation of the method [distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double).

`distance` is an **array** of floats to hold the results. You're probably printing the array, so you're getting the address of the array printed.

Comment: what values does results[1] and results[2] hold? I didn't understand from the documentation - [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))

Comment: Me neither, can we get an answer for that? What are those 'results'?

Answer (score 1):

How do you print result?

Did you try:

```
System.out.println(distance[0]);
```